# I need to set up an python interpreter when i clone a repo on pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, github, pycharm

when I clone a github repository to my pycharm it says that I don't have any python interpreters for that project, but when I open the terminal (pycharm terminal) and type "python name_of_the_file.py" it runs the program without problems. Do I have to set up a python interpreter for the project or not?

ps: pycharm doesn't give any kind of error when I import some module for that project (bult-in module and not bult-in modules)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to tell PyCharm where your Python interpreter is. Go to File -> Project Structure -> Project and select a Project SDK. I suggest creating a new virtual environment for each project.

Opening the terminal and typing `python` uses the system's `PATH` variable to find the executable. PyCharm doesn't use this automatically and you have to set it up.